# string array to sort in abc order

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, if-statement, alphabetical

here is my code with the comments. so im having trouble exiting out of the loop. i know it shoud be if(contd = true) or something then it should exit out, but also if they enter Y to keep going, how do i get back into the loop? 
another thing is how to sort this by abc order. and then how do i do the reverse from Z-A. Thanks for your help, clueless beginner here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string lastName;
        string [] lastName = new string[];    //array list of last names
        int index;
        string contd;


        for (index=0;index++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a last name: ");
            lastName[index] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Keep going? (Y/N): ");   
//prompts user to keep inputting or exit out
                contd = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                if (contd = "n"(Console.ReadLine());
            {
                //exit out of last name input
            }
            else contd = "y"(Console.ReadLine());
            {
                //go back into last name input
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine((index+1) + " last names entered");       
//shows how many last names were entered

        Console.WriteLine();                    //spacing

        //display last names
        Console.WriteLine("Names in Acsending Order"); Console.WriteLine(); 

        for(index=0; index++)                   
//shows the last names in order from A-Z (acsending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lastName[index]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Names in Descending Order"); Console.WriteLine();

        for(index=0; index--)               
//shows back last names in reverse order Z-A (descending)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lastName[index]); Console.WriteLine();

        }
        Console.ReadLine();







    }
}
}
```

Comment: `==` not `=`, as a side note, its really wierd using a for loop as a while loop like that

Comment: you should ask one question at a time.

Comment: Do you *really* want `for` loops without end conditions? Incidentally,  "abc order" is called "alphabetical order" in English.

Comment: Does this even compile? I mean having two variables called lastName...

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea,  this couldn't possibly compile.. even if it did.. it would throw a runtime error with assignment of the array..

Comment: @Breann, have you been introduced to `System.Collections`, `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IList<T>`?

Comment: Omg! I've read the rest of the "code"! Terrible. You need to go read up on some syntax, too!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `do` `while` loop:

```
string d = string.Empty;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("What's your answer?");
    d = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (d != "Y");
```

as for sorting you can use `Array.Sort`

```
Array.Sort(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were doing assignments instead of comparisons, and you also ended your if statement lines with a semicolon. The assignment just sets `contd` to `n` instead of checking if that is its current value and the semicolon at the end would be overlooking the following braces completely like the following..

```
if(contd == "n")
    ;
```

Which is valid code (not sure why you'd want to do this though). Below is what you seem to be looking for but I still think your for loops are a bit strange

```
contd = Console.ReadLine(); // Already a string..
if (contd == "n")
{
    //exit out of last name input
    break;
}
else
{
    //go back into last name input
}
```

To sort these names alphabetically you would be best to look into sorting algorithms such as bubble sort. You could always use linq but I'd imagine this is outside of your classes scope

```
lastName = lastName.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
lastName = lastName.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToArray();
```